# Are there any bindings between .NET and TK

Tags: c#, .net, tk-toolkit

It would be interesting/nice to have something portable like TK to be used in Windows and in Linux with Mono like TK.  Does anyone know of any bindings? or What would be a good place to start in creating bindings.

Answer (score 3):

This page mentions a few C# bindings for Tk:
http://wiki.tcl.tk/6188
Your best bet is probably "Eagle," which is a reimplementation of TCL as a .NET/Mono language:
http://wiki.tcl.tk/6580

Comment: Though personally I choose to use native bindings for each platform. WinForms/WPF for Windows, Cocoa for Mac and GTK for Linux.

Comment: There are Tk themes for each platform that use native widgets.